# Ray Distance Slider

Tags: baking

I have Blender 3.0.0. I am watching videos on normal maps (anvil). During the video, he increases the ray distancing, but since his version of Blender is different from mine, I cannot find the ray distance slider. Can anyone tell me how to access the ray distancing slider in ver. 3.0.0 or higher? Thank you.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is at _Render Properties > Bake > Selected to Active > Max Ray Distance_.

Comment: I hate to give you a diametrically opposite answer to somebody else in comments, but I have to.  Ray distance does not correspond to max ray distance (which should almost never be used) but to ray extrusion.  Of course, given two comments saying opposite things, you'll have to check yourself...

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I couldn't find the spot in the video so I guessed... hastily.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210570/how-the-normal-map-baking-works-what-is-the-ray-direction. Maybe see the last comment from Nathan in that thread?

Comment: I thank you all for your answers. For some reason, I hadn't noticed the drop-down arrow next to "Selected to Active." I found the "Max Ray Distance" slider I was looking for. Thank you all for the quick responses and for helping me get back on track with my project.